# Problem with FireDAC's GetTableNames() method

Tags: delphi, firedac

I am attempting to retrieve all table names from a SQL Server database. The FireDac documentation shows an example:

```pascal
FDConnection1.GetTableNames('NORTHWIND', 'DBO', 'ADQA%', ListBox1.Items,
  [osMy, osSystem, osOther], [tkTable, tkView]);
```

When I use this as a template, substituting my information, I get some issues.

Initially `osMy`, `osOther` and `tkTable` are flagged as errors. I have `FireDac.Comp.Client` in my `uses` list (which is what the documentation says). If I remove those names so I get no compile error when I run it, I get nothing returned. My version looks like this:

```pascal
fdc.GetTableNames('DBName','USerName','tPGC%', ListBox1.Items,[], []);
```

I'd like to see all the table names which start with 'tPGC'.

Any thoughts? Any "real world" examples would help.

Answer (score 1):

You are not getting any results because you are not setting the and `AScopes` `AKinds` parameters to anything meaningful, so `GetTableNames()` doesn't know what type of things you want it to return.

As for the compiler error, make sure the `FireDAC.Phys.Intf` unit is in your `uses` clause.  If that does not resolve the error, then you may have to fully quality the enum values, eg:

```pascal
fdc.GetTableNames('DBName', 'USerName', 'tPGC%', ListBox1.Items,
  [TFDPhysObjectScope.osMy, TFDPhysObjectScope.osSystem, TFDPhysObjectScope.osOther],
  [TFDPhysTableKind.tkTable, TFDPhysTableKind.tkView]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remy,

Adding that unit to my uses clause fixed the compile error, so thanks. Pity the documentation doesn't specify you need this. Also, I've now added those parameters. My code now looks like:

fdc.GetTableNames('DbName','Username','tPGC%', LB.Items,[ osMy ], [ tkTable ]);

Again this doesn't return anything into the listbox.

What I don't know, and can't see anywhere as an example, is if and how to set those parameters. Am I right in assuming 'osMy' means objects that I have permission to get and 'tkTable' means just tables (not Views)?

Does the command return a message on success/failure which could help?

Comment: `[osMy]` is only tables owned by the user you have connected as. Add `osOther` to get the rest besides system tables. Also the second parameter maps to schema in SQL Server which is not often the user (default is dbo and there is no such user for example).